# Sampling a GL_TEXTURE_3D in the Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, fragment-shader, compute-shader

I have a GL_TEXTURE_3D which is of size 16x16x6, it has been populated with floats in a compute shader and I am trying to sample it in the fragment shader.

To make it available to the fragment shader I have this code just before the draw call:

```
//Set the active texture and bind it
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textureID);

//Add the sampler uniform
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(textureID, "TextureSampler"), 0);
```

Then in the fragment shader itself:

```
uniform sampler3D TextureSampler;
```

Then to test that the texture has come through correctly:

```
vec4 test = texture(TextureSampler, ivec3(0,0,0));

color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) * test.x; //or test.y, test.z, test.w
```

Based on this it looks like every texels value is `(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)`

I can't work out why this is? I would expect at coords `(0,0,0)` for the value to be either `(16.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)` or `(16.0,16.0,16.0,16.0)` based on what I set them to in the compute shader

P.S. It might be worth noting that the values are being written to the texture correctly I check inbetween the compute and fragment shader calls using `glGetTexImage()`

Comment: Make sure you either populate your mipmap levels or disable them. You might be writing to the main level, but ignoring the mipmap levels, which the fragment shader then samples.

Comment: So is the 3rd dimension of the GL_TEXTURE_3D the mipmap levels?

Comment: Yep, 3D textures have mipmaps just like normal textures. For example, a 3D texture of size `(x,y,z)` has mipmap levels of size `(x/2,y/2,z/2)`, `(x/4,y/4,z/4)`, and so on. If you don't want mipmapping on the Z axis, use array textures instead.

Comment: Hang on so a 3D texture has `(x,y,z)` coordinates and mipmap levels? So the 3rd dimension isn't the mipmap level? And if this is the case why does the state of mipmapping affect my ability to sample given `(x,y,z)` coordinates

Comment: 3D textures work very similarly to 2D textures, only the data is 3D. Instead of passing in a 2D texture coordinate, you pass in a 3D one. Normalized coordinates and mipmapping still apply to 3D textures. If you want to specify the mipmap level yourself, use `textureLod`. If you want direct access to the texture, use `texelFetch`.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing I use `texture(TextureSampler, ivec3(0,0,0))` which should lookup the value of the texture at coordinates `(0,0,0)` but my result is always `(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)`?